# Could not update model from database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-data-model

Visual studio get stuck when I update my Entity Data Model from database and it takes long time to update the EDM from local DB. What should I do to avoid this problem ?
I use VS 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might happen with your SQL Server compatibility. You can possibly try following things:

1. Set the compatibility level of the database to 110.

To check the compatibility level, run this command:

```
select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = '<YOUR_DATABASE_NAME>'
```

Now, to set the compatibility level, use this script:

```
alter database <YOUR_DATABASE_NAME> set compatibility_level = 110.
```

or
2. Install Service Packs available for visual studio 2013.(Not guarantees solution)

Hope this will help you out.